# Cannot call method 'open' in a Ionic Project

Tags: android, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to load a project of another person. It has a button in the main page that open a webview with an URL. I'm trying to make this project runs but I have problems with the next error, it seems that Ionic didn't know what it is the 'open' property.

This is the error.

```
09-23 16:50:59.785  30847-30847/com.onweb.projectversion I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(5744)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'register' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/ng-cordova.js (5744)
09-23 16:51:02.415  30847-30847/com.onweb.projectversion I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(21157)] "TypeError: Cannot call method 'open' of undefined
            at Scope.LoginController.$scope.registro (file:///android_asset/www/js/LoginCtrl.js:261:38)
            at fn (eval at <anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21972:15), <anonymous>:4:215)
            at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57514:9
            at Scope.$eval (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24673:28)
            at Scope.$apply (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24772:23)
            at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57513:13)
            at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12098:21)
            at triggerMouseEvent (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2865:7)
            at tapClick (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2854:3)
```

Notice that author uses crosswalk with his project.

I've only run the next commands to continue the project:

```
ionic platform add android
ionic browser add crosswalk
ionic build android
ionic run android
```

Some help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the plugin:

```
cordova plugin rm com.shoety.cordova.plugin.inappbrowserxwalk --save
```

and all references of it from the `config.xml` file.

Later, change the method:

```
window.inAppBrowserXwalk.open(url, options);
```

by

```
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

And now, I can compile the code with `ionic run android`